# Confusing python operators

Tags: python

I've run across this piece of code and I can't seem to make sense of it.

```
def _conditional_distribution(self, m, w):
    """
    Conditional distribution (vector of size n_topics).
    """
    vocab_size = self.nzw.shape[1]
    left = (self.nzw[:,w] + self.beta) / \
           (self.nz + self.beta * vocab_size)
    right = (self.nmz[m,:] + self.alpha) / \
            (self.nm[m] + self.alpha * self.n_topics)
    p_z = left * right
    # normalize to obtain probabilities
    p_z /= np.sum(p_z)
    return p_z
```

What does / \ mean? Can anyone tell me what equation this code translates to?

For reference, I believe m and w are both just integers.

Thanks!

Comment: it's a line continuation (the / is for division, the \ is for continuation)

Comment: It's worth noting that PEP-8 highly recommends against doing this kind of line continuation - it's implied within brackets, so changing the way these lines are split would make it far more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/` is the division operator. `\` is used for line continutations. It's the same as:

```
left = (self.nzw[:,w] + self.beta) / (self.nz + self.beta * vocab_size)
```

Just written on two lines instead of one.

Comment: Thank you, will accept in a few minutes... I would've googled this but searching for operators can be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

The backslash `\` before the line break is to continue on the next line, as if the line break was not there.

A more readable way to use multiple lines is to use brackets, like this:

```
left = ((self.nzw[:,w] + self.beta) /
           (self.nz + self.beta * vocab_size))
```

or like this:

```
right = ((self.nmz[m,:] + self.alpha)
         / (self.nm[m] + self.alpha * self.n_topics))
```

If a bracket has no closing counterpart, Python continues to parse on the next line.

Answer (score 2):

`/` is the division operator, and `\` is to continue the current line to the next.  They just look odd when together.